# Как правильно обновить запись laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, функции, mvc

Как правильно создать функцию в контролере laravel .

Есть три функции 
index()
show($id)
create()

необходимо добавить update -уже существующей записи .

Добавил согласно документации данный код в SkladController

```
public function edit( Sklad $sklad )
    {
        return view('sklad.edit', compact('sklad'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Sklad $sklad )
    {
        Sklad::where('id', $sklad)->update($request->all());
        return redirect('sklad');
    }
```

Форма выглядит так

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'sklad']) !!}
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
<div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="title">Название объекта</label>
            <input name="item_name" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $sklad->item_name }}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="item_amount">Кол-во на складе</label>
            <input name="item_amount" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $sklad->item_amount }}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="item_pack">Кол-во зарезервировано</label>
            <input name="item_pack" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $sklad->item_pack }}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="item_image">Изображение</label>
            <input name="item_image" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $sklad->item_image }}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="item_image_alt">Описание изображения</label>
            <input name="item_image_alt" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $sklad->item_image_alt }}" required>
        </div>
</div>
        <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            {!! Form::submit('Добавить объект', ['class'=> 'btn btn-success form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close()!!}
@endsection
```

При нажатии на кнопку происходит ридерикт на страницу со списком, как я и сделал.
Но сама запись не обновляется .
Установил Route в web.php

```
Route::get('sklad/{sklad}/edit', 'SkladController@edit');
Route::patch('sklad', 'SkladController@update');
```

Все равно не чего не обновляется.

Comment: Вот так правильно `php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource --model=Photo`, а дальше по обстановке.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я вижу, у вас тут ошибки и в роуте и в контроллере.
В роуте лучше указать тип запроса 'put'. И url роута, по аналогии с роутом 'edit', должен иметь {sklad} - часть урла, в которой будет id сущности.
Итоговый вариант будет выглядеть так

```
Route::put('sklad/{sklad}', 'SkladController@update');
```

В контроллере:

```
// из-за того, что у роуте мы указали {sklad}
// на вход функции параметров $sklad придёт уже взятая из базы запись 
public function update(Request $request, Sklad $sklad )
    {
        // Поэтому на не нужно искать запись в базе
        // Sklad::where('id', $sklad)->update($request->all());
        // Вот так должно работать
        $sklad->update($request->all());
        return redirect('sklad');
    }
```

Ну и, соответственно, нужно будет поправить url в форме.

Так же в форме нужно исправить тип запроса

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

Comment: `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.`

Comment: web.php 
`
Route::post('sklad', 'SkladController@store');
Route::put('sklad/{sklad}/edit', 'SkladController@update');
`

Comment: Там основная ошибка у автора в том, что он не передает идентификатор сущности, а также не передает метод `POST` (не путать с `_method`). Ну и маршрутам желательно задавать имена. Синтаксиса пакета `laravelcollective` не знаю, но в привычной ситуации `<form action="{{ route('comments.update', $comment) }}" method="post">` А еще лучше [документацию](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html) держать под рукой.